# отправка содержимого txt в telegram powershell

Tags: telegram, powershell

скрипт парсит xml, выдает результат в txt файл. Надо содержимое txt отправлять в telegram.

```
 $token = "*************"
 $сhatid = "*************"
 $text = ""

 $payload = @{ "parse_mode" = "Markdown"; "disable_web_page_preview" = "True" }

 $URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot$token/sendMessage?chat_id=$сhatid&text=$text"

 $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $URL -Method Post `
                              -ContentType "application/json; charset=utf-8" `
                              -Body (ConvertTo-Json -Compress -InputObject $payload)
```

С использованием такого кода отправляется только вручную введенный текст.

Answer (score 1):

все просто и банально. `$text = Get-Content "Filepath"`